# Other ways of verifying reflect.Type for int and float64

Tags: go, reflection, types, casting

In golang, a number in JSON message is always parsed into float64.
In order to detect if it is actually integer, I am using `reflect.TypeOf()` to check its type.
Unfortunately there is no constant that represents `reflect.Type`.

```
intType := reflect.TypeOf(0)
floatType := reflect.TypeOf(0.0)
myType := reflect.TypeOf(myVar)
if myType == intType {
    // do something
}
```

Is there more elegant solution instead of using 0 or 0.0 to get `reflect.Type`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may also use the [`Value.Kind()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Kind) or [`Type.Kind()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) method whose possible values are listed as constants in the `reflect` package, at the doc of the [`Kind`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind) type.

```
myType := reflect.TypeOf(myVar)
if k := myType.Kind(); k == reflect.Int {
    fmt.Println("It's of type int")
} else if k == reflect.Float64 {
    fmt.Println("It's of type float64")
}
```

You can also use it in a `switch`:

```
switch myType.Kind() {
case reflect.Int:
    fmt.Println("int")
case reflect.Float64:
    fmt.Println("float64")
default:
    fmt.Println("Some other type")
}
```

Note that both [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) and [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) has a `Kind()` method, so you can use it if you start with `reflect.ValueOf(myVar)` and also if you start with `reflect.TypeOf(myVar)`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice the Kind() method.

Comment: Note that Kind is not the same as Type. If you declare type myType int, variables of that type will have kind of reflect.Int but type of myType. So which one you want to check for (type or kind) will depend on the specific case.

Comment: This does not work for me to distinguish floats and ints coming from JSON. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422587/need-to-parse-integers-in-json-as-integers-not-floats

Answer (score 0):

To check if interface is of a specific type you can use type assertion with two return values, the second return value is a boolean indicating if the variable is of the type specified. And unlike with a single return value, it will not panic if the variable is of a wrong type.

```
if v, ok := myVar.(int); ok {
    // type assertion succeeded and v is myVar asserted to type int
} else {
    // type assertion failed, myVar wasn't an int
}
```

If there's more types that you need to check then using a type switch is a good idea:

```
switch v := myVar.(type) {
case int:
    // v has type int
case float64:
    // v has type float64
default:
    // myVar was something other than int or float64
}
```

Note however that neither of these actually solve your problem, because like you say, numbers in JSON documents are always parsed into float64s. So if `myVar` is a parsed JSON number, it will always have type of float64 instead of int.

To solve this, I suggest you use the UseNumber() method of the json.Decoder, which causes the decoder to parse numbers as type Number, instead of float64. Take a look at https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number

```
// Assume myVar is a value decoded with json.Decoder with UseNumber() called

if n, ok := myVar.(json.Number); ok {
    // myVar was a number, let's see if its float64 or int64
    // Check for int64 first because floats can be parsed as ints but not the other way around
    if v, err := n.Int64(); err != nil {
        // The number was an integer, v has type of int64
    }
    if v, err := n.Float64(); err != nil {
        // The number was a float, v has type of float64
    }
} else {
    // myVar wasn't a number at all
}
```